# Create cache depending on a variable stored in cookie with Varnish and Magento

Tags: magento, caching, cookies, varnish

let's say I have a variable, that can either be 1, 2 or 3, it is stored in a user cookie. eg:
foo=2

The first time someone access pageX with foo=2, the page shall be cached.
All next visitors with foo=2 in their cookie shall see the same version (hit).

The first time someone access pageX with foo=1, the page shall be cached (as a second version).
All next visitors with foo=1 in their cookie shall see this specific version (hit).

same principle with foo=3

In other words, all pages of my website will have 3 versions, even if the same URL, one for each value of foo in visitor's cookie.

Is this feasible?

thanks,
Rod

Comment: Are you configuring your server or coding Magento here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the answer you are looking for can be found in the varnish docs
https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/wiki/VCLExampleCachingLoggedInUsers

there is a good example in how to use a cookie variable to create a unique hash.

This could also be used to create different pages for the same url. 
Be careful with the browsercache settings of the page. May the page change by url and the browser cache is set to high you might get strange behaviour.